# Can't find post about propositional logic, probably deleted.

Tags: support, deletion, deleted-questions

There was a post on m.se a few days ago, I want to say Thursday or Friday night (SEpt 17th or 18th 2015) where a user was asking for help showing some propositional logic result without using truth tables. It was pretty similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978072/prove-bigp-rightarrow-q-lor-p-rightarrow-r-big-rightarrow-q-lor-r) but the proposition in question was a little more complex with a bunch of nested implications. Something like $((p\vee q)\rightarrow r)\wedge((\neg p\vee s)\rightarrow t)\rightarrow q\wedge s$. That's not right, clearly, but it was something like that. And then the user lists that he's allowed to use the identities $p\vee T=T$, $p\wedge F=F$, etc.

I've been searching for the post with no success, and I presume it's been deleted. Is it easy for someone with high privileges to find such things and share them?

Comment: Users, except for moderators, can't search for deleted posts. Try looking through your browser history.

Comment: @NormalHuman, yeah, that's a good idea. I scoured browser history with no success. which leads me to conclude I must've viewed it in the iOS app. Or dreamed it. Do moderators ever field requests like this?

Comment: They do sometimes. It might help to explain why you need that question; the author could have had a reason to delete it, after all.

Comment: @NormalHuman: Oh I just really wanted to work the problem. I wasn't at leisure to do so when I first saw it. Now when I'm available to go back, the post is missing. Frustrating, though perhaps not a compelling reason for a moderator to circumvent site functionality?

Comment: @Joe It doesn't help for this particular instance, but marking the question as favorite and/or bookmarking its page are good ways to keep track. Now a favorite gets hidden when it is deleted, so bookmarking is the only *real* safeguard to questions getting lost.